# How to load the page as popup dialog without specifying "data-rel" in the caller link

Tags: jquery-mobile

Hi i'm new to Jquery mobile,have some servlet which evaluates username and password from login.html page as,

`if(un.equals("user1") && pd.equals("password1")){

                 RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.html");
             rd.forward(request, response);}
          else {
              RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("loginfailed.html");
              rd.forward(request, response);}
          }`
i

what i'm trying is when login fails loginfailed.html should open as a popup dialog showing login failure notice  [example here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/dialog.html). Pls help me to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using this:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/

Much easier to open from within javascript than the default jquery-mobile dialog, plus it looks like a dialog in that it does not take up the whole page.